# How can I SELECT an 'instance' in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, trigger, etl, change-data-capture

I am reading a paper called "Real Time Delta Extraction Based on Triggers to Support Data Warehousing" from the IEEE and they proposed the following code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER cdc_table ON db.table AS
DECLARE @OPER, @INST, @TAB, @PK, @ID
Select @TAB=table of altered tuple
Select @PK= primary key of @TAB
Select @INST= instance in which @TAB belongs
Begin
IF(@OPER = DELETE)
Select @ID= ID from tuple before deletion;
ELSE
Select @ID= ID from tuple after insertion or update;
ENDIF
Insert into log table @ID, @PK, @TAB, @INST, @OPER;
END;
```

In the line 5 they are asking me to SELECT the instance of the table I am altering. How can I do that?

The log table is defined as follows:

- log id – an integer type field, having a sequential
  number, that stores the execution order of the
  operations;
- instance – a text type field, stores the name of the
  instance whose tuple was altered;
- table – a text type field, stores the name of the table
  whose tuple was altered;
- operation – stores the type of operation that was
  executed: INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE;
- pk column – a text type field, stores the name of the
  column that was used as a unique identifier in the
  table whose tuple was altered;
- tuple id – value of the unique identifier of the altered
  tuple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *really* bad idea to begin with, you're recreating logical replication. Just refer to the [PostgreSQL guide to logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/logical-replication.html).

That said, what you want is the [PostgreSQL plpgsql Trigger "special variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).

- `TG_TABLE_NAME` Data type name; the name of the table that caused the trigger invocation.
- `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA` Data type name; the name of the schema of the table that caused the trigger invocation.